# Else and elif trouble decision

Tags: python, if-statement

Imagine i have the following problem.Write a program to play the following simple game. The player starts with $100. On each
turn a coin is flipped and the player has to guess heads or tails. The player wins $9 for each
correct guess and loses $10 for each incorrect guess. The game ends either when the player
runs out of money or gets to $200.

I have already solved the problem by using a while loop and some if and else statements. I will post the code. When i use if and else my program prints p1_points and p2_points.

```
import random

coin = ['h','t']


def cpu_guess():
    return random.choice(coin)


def player1_guess():
    return input('Digit your choice player 1\n')


def player2_guess():
    return input('Digit your choice player 2\n')


def guessing_game():
    p1_points = 100 #each player starts with 100$
    p2_points = 100 #each player starts with 100$
    while (0 < p1_points <= 200) or (0 < p2_points < 200):
        cpu_choice = cpu_guess()
        print(cpu_choice)
        player1_choice = player2_guess()
        player2_choice = player2_guess()
        if player1_choice == cpu_choice:
            p1_points += 45
            print(p1_points)
        else:
            p1_points = p1_points - 45
            print(p1_points)
        if player2_choice == cpu_choice:
            p2_points += 45
            print(p2_points)
        else:
            p2_points = p2_points - 45
            print(p2_points)
    if p1_points > p2_points:
        print('Player 1 won the game (',p1_points,'-',p2_points,')')
    elif p2_points > p1_points:
        print('Player 2 won the game (', p2_points, '-', p1_points, ')')
    else:
        print('Even game (',p1_points,'-',p2_points,')')
    return p1_points,p2_points


print(guessing_game())
```

However imagine i want to put the following code.

```
 if player1_choice == cpu_choice:
            p1_points += 45
            print(p1_points)
        elif player_choice != cpu_choice
            p1_points = p1_points - 45
            print(p1_points)
        elif player2_choice == cpu_choice:
            p2_points += 45
            print(p2_points)
        else:
            p2_points = p2_points - 45
            print(p2_points)
```

In this situation why are only the player 1 points printed and not the player 2 points aswell?

Comment: *"why are only the player 1 points printed and not the player 2 points aswell?"* - Under what logical condition would you expect that code execute both `print(p1_points)` and `print(p2_points)`?  Consider the semantics of what the word "else" means.  (Hint: `elif` is short for "else if".)

Comment: if statement is executed first if it is not true we skip to the next elif and we print, I thought elif and else worked the same way

Comment: The first two conditions, `player1_choice == cpu_choice` and `player_choice != cpu_choice`, cover all possible outcomes.  One of those will _always_ be true.  The code never makes it to the other two conditions.

Comment: so you are saying the elif statement will only be executed if necessary?

Comment: When you have an `if/elif/else` block, the code underneath the first true statement is executed, and no other code.

Comment: Please see the [mcve] guidelines -- we ask that questions contain *the shortest possible working code* that can be used to demonstrate a problem or test whether it's adequately fixed. This means that if user input isn't part of your question, the code retrieving input can be replaced with a hardcoded constant; if looping isn't part of your question, the loop can be replaced with a single invocation; etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want two *separate* if/else blocks:

```
if player1_choice == cpu_choice:
    p1_points += 45
else:
    p1_points -= 45
print(p1_points)

if player2_choice == cpu_choice:
    p2_points += 45
else:
    p2_points -= 45
print(p2_points)
```